# Unwanted too many arguments error being printed out

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script that logs into remote nodes and returns the services being run on that node.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a SERVICES=('redis-server' 'kube-controller-manager' 'kubelet' 'postgres' 'mongod' 'elasticsearch');    

for svc in "${SERVICES[@]}"
do

     RESULT=`ssh 172.29.219.109 "ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $svc"`
     if [ -z ${RESULT} ]
     then
        echo "Is Empty" > /dev/null
     else
        echo "$svc is running on this node"
     fi
done
```

Now the output of `ssh 172.29.219.109 "ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $svc"` on the node is ::

```
postgres  2102     1  0 Jan29 ?        00:24:27 /opt/PostgresPlus/pgbouncer/bin/pgbouncer -d /opt/PostgresPlus/pgbouncer/share/pgbouncer.ini
postgres  2394     1  0 Jan29 ?        00:20:10 /opt/PostgresPlus/9.4AS/bin/edb-postgres -D /opt/PostgresPlus/9.4AS/data
postgres  2431  2394  0 Jan29 ?        00:00:01 postgres: logger process   
postgres  2434  2394  0 Jan29 ?        00:07:15 postgres: checkpointer process   
postgres  2435  2394  0 Jan29 ?        00:01:10 postgres: writer process   
postgres  2436  2394  0 Jan29 ?        00:03:27 postgres: wal writer process   
postgres  2437  2394  0 Jan29 ?        00:20:03 postgres: autovacuum launcher process   
postgres  2438  2394  0 Jan29 ?        00:37:00 postgres: stats collector process   
postgres  2494     1  0 Jan29 ?        00:08:12 /opt/PostgresPlus/9.4AS/bin/pgagent -l 1 -s /var/log/ppas-agent-9.4.log hostaddr=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres
postgres  2495  2394  0 Jan29 ?        00:11:25 postgres: postgres postgres 127.0.0.1[59246] idle
```

When I run the script, I do get the result I want but Im getting an unwanted message which seems to be related to the variable in which I am storing my result.

```
# ./map_services_to_nodes.sh 
./map_services_to_nodes.sh: line 12: [: too many arguments
postgres is found on this node
```

The Algo that I im using is ::

- Search for all services defined in my array.
- Store the result in a variable.
- If Variable is empty, that means that service is not running.
- If its not empty, service is running.

Comment: quotes..........

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ would have caught this for you without getting humans involved.

Comment: (on a different point, you're better off using `pgrep` than `ps | grep`; built for the purpose, already knows how to avoid matching itself)

Comment: (...on a different different point, you're better off asking your local process supervision system which services are running. For instance, if your OS uses systemd, `if systemctl is-active redis-server; then echo "redis-server is running"; fi`. There are equivalents for every other supervision system worth its salt -- Upstart, DJB daemontools, runit, etc etc -- that way you don't get a false positive from `vim mongod.conf` matching your grep).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape `$` (to avoid local expansion) and `"` when using inside `ssh` command, also avoid using the outdated back-ticks for command-substitution, use `$(..)`, see [Why Use $(STATEMENT) instead of legacy `STATEMENT`](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006)

```
RESULT=$(ssh 172.29.219.109 "ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep \$svc")
```

and double quote variables inside `test` operator,

```
if [ -z "${RESULT}" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the below

```
if [ -z ${RESULT} ]
```

to

```
if [ -z "${RESULT}" ]
```

and it worked.

```
# ./map_services_to_nodes.sh 
postgres is found on this node
```